# Tic Tac Toe C++ linked error ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile but I keep getting this error, does anyone see where my mistake is?

Error:

C:\Users\Moody\AppData\Local\Temp\ccyClPvo.o    Mattingly_Section2_Lab11.cpp:(.text+0x9d9): undefined reference to `startGame()'

C:\Users\Moody\Documents\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

```
// Computer Tic tac toe,

// Include the iostream library
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
// Using the standard namespace
using namespace std;
// declare global variables
char Board [9];

// Declare Functions
void showBoard ( );
bool moveIsValid (int m );
int whoWon();
int playerScore = 0;
int computerScore = 0;
int ties = 0;
void playAgain();
void startGame();

int main ( )
{   
void startGame(); 
{
// Seed the random number
srand (time (NULL) );
// Declare Global Variables
int Whose_Turn = 1; // 1 means players turn and 2 means player 2 turns
int Move; // Store where the players wants to move
int Total_Moves = 0;
int num_players = 0;

// Assigns values to the playing board
Board[0] = '0';
Board[1] = '1';
Board[2] = '2';
Board[3] = '3';
Board[4] = '4';
Board[5] = '5';
Board[6] = '6';
Board[7] = '7';
Board[8] = '8';


cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe.\n Enter 0 to watch computers duke it the fuck out in some good old tic tacers, bro" << endl;
cin >> num_players;

if (num_players == 0) {
    while (whoWon ( ) ==0 && Total_Moves < 9) {
      do {
        // Show the board
        showBoard ();
        // Tell which player to move
        if (Whose_Turn ==1) {
          cout << "The First Computer's move is: " << Move << endl;
          Move = rand() % 9;
        } else {
          Move = rand() % 9;
          cout << "The Second Computer's move is: " << Move << endl;
        }
        // Get move
       // cout << "Enter the number of spot you'd like to move" << endl;
       // cin >> Move;
      } while (moveIsValid (Move) != true);
      // Add 1 to Total_Moves
      Total_Moves++;
      // Change whose turn it is
      switch (Whose_Turn) {
        case (1): {
          Board[Move] = 'x';
          Whose_Turn = 2;
          break;
        }
        case (2): {
          Board[Move] = 'o';
          Whose_Turn = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    // show the board
    showBoard ();
    if (whoWon () == 1) {
      // show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << "Computer 1 has won the game!" << endl;
      ++playerScore;
    } 
    if (whoWon () == 2) {
      // Show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << " The Second Computer has won the game! " << endl;
      ++computerScore;
    } 
    if (Total_Moves==9 && !whoWon()) {
      // Show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << "It's a tie game!" << endl;
      ++ties;

    }
    cout << "Computer 1: " << playerScore << " "<< "Computer 2: " << computerScore << " Ties: "<< ties << endl;
  }
  system ("Pause");
  return 0;
}
}
void showBoard ( ) {
  cout << endl;
  cout << Board[0] << " | " << Board[1] << " | " << Board[2] << endl;
  cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
  cout << Board[3] << " | " << Board[4] << " | " << Board[5] << endl;
  cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
  cout << Board[6] << " | " << Board[7] << " | " << Board[8] << endl;
  cout << endl;
}

bool moveIsValid (int m ) {
  if (Board[m] != 'x' && Board[m] != 'o') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int whoWon ( ) {
if (Board[0] == Board[1] && Board[1] == Board[2]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[3] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[5]) {
  if (Board[3] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[6] == Board[7] && Board[7] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[6] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[0] == Board[3] && Board[3] == Board[6]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[1] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[7]) {
  if (Board[1] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[2] == Board[5] && Board[5] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[2] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[0] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[2] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[6]) {
  if (Board[2] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}

return 0;
}
void playAgain()
{
    char answer;
    int Whose_Turn;
    int Total_Moves;
    cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N)" << endl;

    while (cin >> answer)
    {
        if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
        {
            Whose_Turn = 1;
            Total_Moves = 0;
            cout << endl;
            startGame(); 

        }
        else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
        {
            cout << endl << "Bye!" << endl;
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a correct input: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            string str;
            getline(cin, str);
            answer = str[0];
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot define a function within another function like that.

Comment: Would you know what to do to fix it? Removing the void startGame(); from inside int main() hasn't worked for me. I feel like a doofus.

Comment: You defined the other functions ok.

Answer (score 0):

1. First things first I'm pretty sure you cannot define a function [ startGame() ] inside main() like that or in any other function for that matter.
2. The function definition syntax for startGame() is not correct either. You do not terminate i.e. remove the semi-colon (void startGame() ; {)
3. Your function startGame() is void but you are returning a value at the end of your function i.e. return 0

This should compile and run. Try this:

```
// Computer Tic tac toe,

// Include the iostream library
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
// Using the standard namespace
using namespace std;
// declare global variables
char Board [9];

// Declare Functions
void showBoard ( );
bool moveIsValid (int m );
int whoWon();
int playerScore = 0;
int computerScore = 0;
int ties = 0;
void playAgain();
void startGame();

int main ( )
{   
  startGame();
  return 0;
}


void startGame()
{
// Seed the random number
srand (time (NULL) );
// Declare Global Variables
int Whose_Turn = 1; // 1 means players turn and 2 means player 2 turns
int Move; // Store where the players wants to move
int Total_Moves = 0;
int num_players = 0;

// Assigns values to the playing board
Board[0] = '0';
Board[1] = '1';
Board[2] = '2';
Board[3] = '3';
Board[4] = '4';
Board[5] = '5';
Board[6] = '6';
Board[7] = '7';
Board[8] = '8';


cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe.\n Enter 0 to watch computers duke it the fuck out in some good old tic tacers, bro" << endl;
cin >> num_players;

if (num_players == 0) {
    while (whoWon ( ) ==0 && Total_Moves < 9) {
      do {
        // Show the board
        showBoard ();
        // Tell which player to move
        if (Whose_Turn ==1) {
          cout << "The First Computer's move is: " << Move << endl;
          Move = rand() % 9;
        } else {
          Move = rand() % 9;
          cout << "The Second Computer's move is: " << Move << endl;
        }
        // Get move
       // cout << "Enter the number of spot you'd like to move" << endl;
       // cin >> Move;
      } while (moveIsValid (Move) != true);
      // Add 1 to Total_Moves
      Total_Moves++;
      // Change whose turn it is
      switch (Whose_Turn) {
        case (1): {
          Board[Move] = 'x';
          Whose_Turn = 2;
          break;
        }
        case (2): {
          Board[Move] = 'o';
          Whose_Turn = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    // show the board
    showBoard ();
    if (whoWon () == 1) {
      // show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << "Computer 1 has won the game!" << endl;
      ++playerScore;
    } 
    if (whoWon () == 2) {
      // Show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << " The Second Computer has won the game! " << endl;
      ++computerScore;
    } 
    if (Total_Moves==9 && !whoWon()) {
      // Show the board
      showBoard();
      cout << "It's a tie game!" << endl;
      ++ties;

    }
    cout << "Computer 1: " << playerScore << " "<< "Computer 2: " << computerScore << " Ties: "<< ties << endl;
  }
  system ("Pause");
}

void showBoard ( ) {
  cout << endl;
  cout << Board[0] << " | " << Board[1] << " | " << Board[2] << endl;
  cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
  cout << Board[3] << " | " << Board[4] << " | " << Board[5] << endl;
  cout << "--+---+--" << endl;
  cout << Board[6] << " | " << Board[7] << " | " << Board[8] << endl;
  cout << endl;
}

bool moveIsValid (int m ) {
  if (Board[m] != 'x' && Board[m] != 'o') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int whoWon ( ) {
if (Board[0] == Board[1] && Board[1] == Board[2]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[3] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[5]) {
  if (Board[3] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[6] == Board[7] && Board[7] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[6] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[0] == Board[3] && Board[3] == Board[6]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[1] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[7]) {
  if (Board[1] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[2] == Board[5] && Board[5] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[2] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[0] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[8]) {
  if (Board[0] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
if (Board[2] == Board[4] && Board[4] == Board[6]) {
  if (Board[2] == 'x') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}

return 0;
}
void playAgain()
{
    char answer;
    int Whose_Turn;
    int Total_Moves;
    cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N)" << endl;

    while (cin >> answer)
    {
        if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
        {
            Whose_Turn = 1;
            Total_Moves = 0;
            cout << endl;
            startGame(); 

        }
        else if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
        {
            cout << endl << "Bye!" << endl;
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a correct input: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            string str;
            getline(cin, str);
            answer = str[0];
        }
   }
}
```